# Add string in filename before pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I need to add string in between of filename where a pattern is matched.

Sample filenames:

```
file_1_my001
file_11_my0012
file_65_my_012
```

I would like to rename them as:

```
file_1_my_copied_001
file_11_my_copied_0012
file_65_my_copied_012
```

Pattern is `<any string>0<any string>`

My logic was to first fetch the numerical format starting with 0, store in variable as pattern, then search for the variable and replace it by `_copied_<variable>`. I tried fetching numbers as:

```
ls | sed -e s/[^0-9]//g
```

but above command is fetching all numbers in filename eg. `1001, 110012, 65012` I am unable to make it search for numerical format starting with 0. Please guide.

Comment: Please let us know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: @ghoti Sure, edited

Comment: Are you trying to rename (`mv`) files or change the values of a list of file names stored in a file or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `perl` based `rename` command:

```
$ touch file_1_my001 file_11_my0012 file_65_my_012
$ rename -n 's/_?(?=0)/_copied_/' file_*
rename(file_11_my0012, file_11_my_copied_0012)
rename(file_1_my001, file_1_my_copied_001)
rename(file_65_my_012, file_65_my_copied_012)
```

- `_?(?=0)` zero or one instance of `_` followed by `0`
- `-n` option is for dry run, after it looks good, remove the option for actual renaming

If `perl` based `rename` is not available, try:

```
$ for file in file_* ; do echo mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed 's/_\?0/_copied_0/'); done
mv file_11_my0012 file_11_my_copied_0012
mv file_1_my001 file_1_my_copied_001
mv file_65_my_012 file_65_my_copied_012
```

If it is okay, change `echo mv` to `mv` for actual renaming

If optional `_` before `0` is not present, it is easier to use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ touch file_1_my001 file_11_my0012 file_65_my012
$ for file in file_* ; do echo mv "$file" "${file/0/_copied_0}"; done
mv file_11_my0012 file_11_my_copied_0012
mv file_1_my001 file_1_my_copied_001
mv file_65_my012 file_65_my_copied_012
```

Comment: Perfect! It does the job well

Comment: What if I do not have optional `_` before `0`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | sed -e 's/\([_]*0\)/_copied_0/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like,

```
$ sed -E "s/(.*[^0-9]+)(0[0-9]*)/\1_copied_\2/"
```